# underscore "class needs to be abstract since method is not defined" error

Tags: scala, generics, compiler-errors, abstract-class

With scala 2.10.2, I have a code that `extends` from class `scala.swing.ListView[SomeClass]` and I get this error:

```
src/some.scala:100: error: class Some_Renderer needs to be abstract, since method componentFor in class Renderer of type (list: scala.swing.ListView[_ <: SomeClass], isSelected: Boolean, focused: Boolean, a: SomeClass, index: Int)scala.swing.Component is not defined
  private class Some_Renderer extends ListView.Renderer[SomeClass]
```

**EDIT: "an extra Note" is actually the error here, as commented `B[String]` must be `B[_]`.**

**EDIT: some real example follows**

I have reproduced it as the following example, though with an extra Note:

```
scala> class B[A] { val m : Int = 0 }
defined class B

scala> abstract class C[A] { def f(l: B[_]):Int }
defined class C

scala> private class D extends C[String] { def f(l: B[String]):Int = { l.m } }
<console>:9: error: class D needs to be abstract, since method f in class C of type (l: B[_])Int is not defined
(Note that B[_] does not match B[String]: their type parameters differ)
   private class D extends C[String] { def f(l: B[String]):Int = { l.m } }
```

**EDIT: MWE**

```
import scala.swing.{Component, Label, ListView}
class Test
object Retn extends Label { opaque = false }
private class TestRenderer extends ListView.Renderer[Test]
{
    def componentFor(list: ListView[_], isSelected: Boolean, focused: Boolean, test: Test, index: Int): Component =
    {
        val retn = Retn
        retn
    }
}
<console>:9: error: class TestRenderer needs to be abstract, since method componentFor in class Renderer of type (list: scala.swing.ListView[_ <: Test], isSelected: Boolean, focused: Boolean, a: Test, index: Int)scala.swing.Component is not defined
           private class TestRenderer extends ListView.Renderer[Test]
                         ^
```

**EDIT: MWE**

I am only trying to patch that line of code, and do `scala` programming by *no* means.
Yet I do not understand what is the problem with this example. I found similar questions 
but not with this underscore ("`_`") thing.

The example tries to provide an implementation for the abstract method `f` from class `C[A]`.

Thank s for your comments or answers about this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`B[_]` is an "[existential type](http://www.drmaciver.com/2008/03/existential-types-in-scala/)", but you can understand this as being roughly equivalent to `B[Any]`.

The error message tells you `Note that B[_] does not match B[String]: their type parameters differ`. You wouldn't expect to be able to replace a `List[Any]` parameter with a `List[String]` in an overridden definition, would you? Because then what happens when you pass it a `List[Int]`, which is also a bona fide `List[Any]` as required in the abstract class?

Solution: replace `def f(l: B[String]):Int = ...` with `def f(l: B[_]):Int = ...`

**Edit**: the problem with your MWE is that you've defined the `TestRenderer` class on one line, then you've written a code block delimited by `{` `}` on the next... this will be interpreted as you intend in normal code (although it's better to put the `{` at the end of the previous line) but since you're in the REPL the class definition is interpreted as soon as you hit return. Solution: either put the `{` at the end of the `private class ...` line or type in `:paste` to allow you to write the lot before it's interpreted.

... at least, I assume that's what your problem is. The MWE works fine for me in scala 2.10.0 REPL, although I get a slightly different error message if I just type in the `private class ...` line.

Comment: Okay, that was the another error with `B[_]`; added now an MWE edited, with exact reproduction of the error. thank s.

Comment: Indeed 2.10.0 encounters no problems. But i had to use an out-of-tree installation, sice my distribution has only 2.9.* and 2.10.2 builds. Can't seem to figure this one out...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the constraints are in your original case, but in your example, could you use B[_] instead of B[String] when you override f?

```
class D extends C[String] { def f(l: B[_]):Int = { l.m } }
```

The underscore in this case is an existential type, and can can be any subtype of Any. See [here](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596155957/ScalasTypeSystem.html#ExistentialTypes) for more information on existential types in Scala.

Comment: ("*It was with us all the way*", `Bishop`/"*Alien 3*"), i mean the confusion; there isn't even a choice to "**answer your question**". The scala-2.10.2 build applied a patch (when jdk-1.7 was the case) that changed `componentFor(list:ListView[_], ...)` into `componentFor(list:ListView[_ <: A], ...)` throughout `swing`, so that although i `diff`ed via the distro **2.10.2** against **2.10.1** in a troubleshooting attempt, in fact i haven't gone that far to have had the patch applied; as a result, in the client code i always considered `ListView[_]` whereas distro build had `ListView[_ <: A]` ...

Comment: I think you're saying you want to post an answer to your own question, right? You should be able to use "Add Another Answer" below if you like.

Comment: "how could i?" it is what i meant: i don't have this *choice*, since the **EDIT**ed question is wrong, it is meaningless in itself (except the part you posted comments about, thank s).